# Let $V$ be spherically symmetric and $W$ i.i.d. Gaussian. Then $E[V|V+W=t]=g(\|t\|)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

A random vector $V \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be spherically symmetric. If for every orthogonal matrix  $A$   the distribution of $AV$ is the same as the distribution of $V$.

**My question:** Let $W$ be  i.i.d. zero mean Gaussian random variable.     Can we show that  for a spherically symmetric $V$ the conditional expectation 
\begin{align}
E[V|V+W=t]=   g(\|t\|). 
\end{align} 
That is the conditional expectation is only a function of the magnitude.

**My attempt:** 
\begin{align}
E[V|V+W=t]= \int  V  \frac{f_W(t-v)}{f_{V+W}(t)} dP_V(v)= \frac{\int  v  f_W(t-v) dP_V(v)}{f_{V+W}(t)}= \frac{E[ V  f_W(t-V) ]}{f_{V+W}(t)}
\end{align}

Therefore, we can show that the two functions in the above ratio only depend on $\|t\|$.

Observe that we can write $t= \|t\| u_t$  where $u_t$ is a unit vector. Then, for any orthogonal matrix $A$
\begin{align}
f_{V+W}(t)=f_{V+W}(\|t\|, u_t)&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} E[ e^{-\frac{\|t-V  \|^2}{2}} ]\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} E[ e^{-\frac{\|t-AV  \|^2}{2}} ]\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} E[ e^{-\frac{\|tA^{-1}-V  \|^2}{2}} ]\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} E[ e^{-\frac{\|t A^T-V  \|^2}{2}} ]\\
&= f_{V+W}(tA^T)\\
&= f_{V+W}(\|t\|,  u_t A^T)
\end{align} 
Since, $A$ was arbitrary  we have that $f_{V+W}(t)=h(\|t\|)$(i.e., only depends on the magnitute).

Now I am not sure how to show that $E[ V  f_W(t-V) ]$ only depends on $\|t\|$?

Comment: It’ll depend on the direction of $t.$ Consider what happens if the variance of $W$ is taken to be nearly zero - the conditional expectation you want will be nearly $t.$

Comment: @Dap  Ok. But it would be something of the form $v_t g(\|t\| )$, correct? Where $v_t$ is unit vector.

Comment: Sounds plausible

Comment: @Dap Do you think that it is true that if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix then $A E[V|V+W]= E[V|V+W]$ a.s. ?

Comment: No, for the same reason: take $W$ to be nearly zero (or just zero). Then $AE[V\mid V+W]\approx AV$ is different from $E[V\mid V+W]\approx V$ in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ satisfying $Af(t)=f(At)$ for all orthogonal $A$ is of the form $f(t)=g(\|t\|)u_t.$
In other words, $f(ru)=g(r)u$ for all $r\geq 0$ and unit vectors $u.$ To see this, first note that $f(ru)$ must be fixed by all orthogonal transformations fixing $u,$ and must therefore be parallel to $u,$ and so of the form $g(r,u)u.$ But then $g(r,Au)Au=f(rAu)=Af(ru)=Ag(r,u)u=g(r,u)Au,$ so $g(r,u)$ is independent of $u.$

For any orthogonal $A,$
$$AE[V\mid V+W=t]=E[AV\mid V+W=t]=E[V\mid A^{-1}V+W=t]=E[V\mid V+W=At]$$
where I have used that $V$ and $W$ are independent, that $V$ has the same distribution as $A^{-1}V,$ and that $W$ has the same distribution as $AW.$
This shows that the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=E[V\mid V+W+t]$ satisfies $Af(t)=f(At).$

Comment: Do functions such that $Af(t)=f(At)$ for orthgonal matrices have a name?

Comment: @Lisa: $f$ is orthogonally equivariant, see https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XK3uhrVefXQC&lpg=PA275&ots=KnC-OnoITD&dq=%22orthogonally%20equivariant%22&pg=PA276#v=onepage&q&f=false for a slightly more general result

Comment: Just a quick question. We have that $\|f(t)\| =g(\|t\|)$, right?

Comment: @Lisa: yes - just apply $\|\cdot\|$ to both sides of $f(t)=g(\|t\|)u_t.$